# Use of entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-entities

I am trying to use entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity) where:

**$entity_type** = The entity type; e.g. 'node' or 'user'.

**$entity** = The entity from which to extract values.

I have never used this function and don't understand what the second parameter (i.e. **$entity**) is supposed to be.

I would love to see an example code with this function being used. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function return `array($id, $vid, $bundle);`

Example:

```
// Define $entity_type.
// Could be 'node', 'user', 'file', 'taxonomy_term' etc.
$entity_type = 'node';

// Get $entity object, in our case $node with nid = 1
$entity = node_load(1);

// print_r will give us something like:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1
//     [1] => 4
//     [2] => page
// )
// Where [0] is nid, [1] is vid and [2] is bundle name of a node with nid = 1
print_r(entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity));
```

It's better to use function like that:

```
list($id, $vid, $bundle) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);
```